# CiviMail is not sending immediate mailing and scheduled mailing is working partially

Tags: civimail, scheduled-job

In my first CiviMail "real" massive mailing, I tried an immediate mail (500 contacts), but no mail where sent.
Then I force  the "Send Scheduled Mailings" job, in order to start the shipping, but, after some time waiting, I obtain a white page and the mail really sent where 20.
A second forced "Send Scheduled Mailings" sent other 150 mails, after the white page.

What is happening?

Some details:

- the maximum mail split number is set to 400
- no message in the configAndLog folder
- the job log is the following:

*Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}*

*Full message: 
Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailingss*